# Passing variables through multiple partials (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I am trying to pass instance variables through multiple partials and having trouble.  `undefined local variable or method "product"`

Application.html.erb"

```
    <%= render 'shared/footer', :product => @product %>
```

_footer.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/my_form', :product => product %>
```

_my_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for( product ) %>
```

UPDATE:

I'm starting to think it might be that the instance variable @product is just not being set/passed for the redirect.  Could the following be causing the issue? Opened different issue here:

[Instance variable not set with redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109160/instance-variable-not-set-with-redirect)

Comment: I might not be understanding the question, but does changing `product` to `@product` in the second and third lines work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this syntax:

**Application.html.erb"**

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/footer', locals: {:product => @product} %>
```

**_footer.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/my_form', locals: {:product => product} %>
```

**_my_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for( product ) %>
```

Notice the use of `partial:` and `locals:`

Comment: You are posting the exact same thing I posted 14 min earlier.

Comment: @PeterdeRidder, I updated my post.  However, I'm thinking the instance variable is not being set correctly now.  also, you post and marwen's post are slightly different, the second line is '@product' vs product for the my_form partial.

Comment: Ah my bad, was a typo. Since you are calling shared/footer with a local variable you should use that local variable in the footer. Hence you should use product there instead of @product. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass local variables, you should use this syntax:

```
 <%= render partial: 'shared/footer', locals: { product: @product } %>
 <%= render partial: 'shared/my_form', locals: { product: product } %>
 <%= form_for( product ) %>
```

For reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html (3.4.4)