# Instance variable not set with redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

What would cause my instance variable @product to not be set/passed for the redirect.  Product is an ActiveModel object, not ActiveRecord. to be more specific, the @product variable is not appearing in the redirect_to(new_services_path) or redirect_to(home_path) pages.  As the @product variable need to populate a form in my footer that is on every page.

Application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  before_filter :set_product

  private

  def set_product
    @product ||= Product.new
  end
end
```

Product_controller:

```
  def new
  end


 def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    if  @product.category == "wheels"
      redirect_to(new_services_path) 
    else
      redirect_to(home_path) 
    end
  end
```

Issue related to this original post..
[Passing variables through multiple partials (rails 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104715/passing-variables-through-multiple-partials-rails-4)

Comment: @Product... maybe @product?

Comment: that was a mistype on stackoverflow. fixed it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, but it http://ideone.com/GXHLp6 can solve your problem

Comment: variable still not being passed on redirect

Comment: @henb, I am trying to redirect to another controller, but pass the `@product` variable so it populates my form_for in a footer.

Comment: Thinking I might need to set a session variable.

Comment: It's a redirect-i.e., a new request, a new instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instance variables are not passed on a redirect.

Consequently, you have no `@product` object at the time you are reaching the `before_filter` and so you're just creating the new and empty `Product` object each time.

ActiveModel objects can't persist from session to session, but you can keep the attributes in your session store and use that in your before_filter

```
def set_product
  @product = Product.new(session[:product]) if session[:product]
  @product ||= Product.new
end
```

And in your create method you move the form params to the session...

```
def create
  session[:product] = params[:product]
  set_product 
  if @product.category == 'wheels'
  ---
```

Notice that we called `set_product` explicitly in the create method because the session[:product] had been re-established.

In case you're wondering WHY the instance variable is lost... in the create method you are in an instance of ProductController and that instance has it's own instance variables.  When you redirect, you are instructing rails to create a NEW instance of some other (or the same) controller, and that brand new controller object, it has no instance variables established.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Do I need to worry about destroying the session?

Answer (score 2):

To add to `SteveTurczyn`'s answer, you need to read up about [object orientated programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). After I did, all the `@instance` variable stuff became a *lot* clearer.

[image]

[**Very** good write-up](http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/09/object-oriented-programming-in-a-nutshell/)

---

**Ruby** is object-orientated, meaning every time you send a request, it has to invoke all the relative *objects* (classes) for you to interact with:

The duration of this request is called an *instance*. Redirecting invokes a *new* request; hence a new *instance* of your various classes.

This is why you have to invoke new `@instance` variables each time your users interact with a new action:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @model = Model.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @model = Model.find params[:id] #-> new request = new instance
   end
end
```

--

Thus, when you ask...

> `@product` variable need to populate a form in my footer that is on every page.

You need to remember that this will be invoked *every* time your actions are rendered. You already do this; the problem is that you're not persisting the data:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  before_filter :set_product

  private

  def set_product
    @product ||= Product.new #-> after "create", params[:product] = nil (new instance)
  end
end
```

`@SteveTurczyn` got it when he mentioned putting the data into the session. As per the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark)...

> HTTP is a [stateless protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). Sessions make it stateful.

Answer (score -1):

The solution mentioned by Steve will work for smaller amount of data but what about fetching some records and passing it with redirect_to. The session does not allow us that much space.

What i did is that i set those records in a flash object and when it redirected to the page flash rendered the data for me successfully.

```
flash[:products] = @products
redirect_to users_path
```

Let me know, how it works...

Comment: this is a nice quick hack, but still we need to consider it is a anti pattern